# C# - request.GetResponse()

Tags: c#

I am making a web browser and I am trying to get a favicon to display on a tabpage. I am having some trouble with some code.

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

In particular, here is the full code:

```
int selpage = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;

dynamic iconURL = web.Url.AbsoluteUri + "/favicon.ico";
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(iconURL);

System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
dynamic mimage = Image.FromStream(stream);

tabControl1.TabPages[selpage].ImageIndex = mimage;
```

Here is the error it is providing me with:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.WebResponse'
>   to 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can you maybe describe the problem?

Comment: My Apologies @David

I have added the error code and string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And if you are using .net 4.5 you should have a look at HttpClient